# How to create callback function using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on the jquery to call a function to get the return value that I want to store for the variable `email_number` when I refresh on a page.

When I try this:

```
function get_emailno(emailid, mailfolder) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getemailnumber.php',
        type: 'POST',

        data : {
            emailid: emailid,
            mailfolder: mailfolder
        },

        success: function(data)
        {
            email_number = data;
        }
    });
    return email_number;
}
```

I will get the return value as `6` as only when I use `alert(email_number)` after the `email_number = data;`, but I am unable to get the value outside of a function.

Here is the full code:

```
var email_number = '';

// check if page refreshed or reloaded
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    var hash    = window.location.hash;
    var mailfolder = hash.split('/')[0].replace('#', '');
    var emailid = 'SUJmaWg4RTFRQkViS1RlUzV3K1NPdz09';
    get_emailno(emailid, mailfolder);
}

function get_emailno(emailid, mailfolder) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getemailnumber.php',
        type: 'POST',

        data : {
            emailid: emailid,
            mailfolder: mailfolder
        },

        success: function(data)
        {
            email_number = data;
        }
    });
    return email_number;
}
```

However, I have been researching and it stated that I would need to use callback via ajax but I have got no idea how to do this.

I have tried this and I still don't get a return value outside of the `get_emailno` function.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getemailnumber.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,

        data : {
            emailid: emailid,
            mailfolder: mailfolder
        },

        success: function(data)
        {
            email_number = data;
        }
    });
```

I am getting frustrated as I am unable to find the solution so I need your help with this. What I am trying to do is I want to call on a `get_emailno` function to get the return value to store in the `email_number` variable.

Can you please show me an example how I could use a callback function on ajax to get the return value where I can be able to store the value in the `email_number` variable?

Thank you.

Comment: We just closed this question. Don't post the same question over again. Read the link we provided in the last question you posted.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @ScottMarcus No this is a different question so please check my question carefully.

Comment: @chrisoojer, it's *almost* same question. However, to give you some quick help, the callback you researched about is talking of the `success`, `error` and `complete` callbacks. You already have `success` callback in your code

Comment: UdoE Thank you for your advice. So what callback is the best for me to use? is it `complete` callback?

Comment: @chrisoojer, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the `$.ajax()` method returns a `jqXHR` object (this reads fully as jquery XMLHttpRequest object).

When you return data from the server in another function like this

```
function get_emailno(emailid, mailfolder) {

    $.ajax({ 
        // ajax settings
    });
    return email_number;
}
```

Note that `$.ajax ({...})` call is asynchronous. Hence, the code within it doesn't necessarily execute before the last return statement. In other words, the `$.ajax ()` call is *deferred* to execute at some time in the future, while the return statement executes immediately.

Consequently, jquery specifies that you handle (or respond to) the execution of ajax requests using callbacks and **not** return statements.

There are two ways you can define callbacks.

**1.** Define them within the jquery ajax request settings like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    // other ajax settings 
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function() {},
    complete: function() {},
});
```

**2.** Or chain the callbacks to the returned jqXHR object like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    // other ajax settings 
}).done(function(data) {}).fail(function() {}).always(function() {});
```

The two methods are equivalent. `success:` is equivalent to `done()`,  `error:` is equivalent to `fail()` and  `complete:` is equivalent to `always()`.

On when it is appropriate to use which function: use `success:` to handle the case where the returned data is what you expect; use `error:` if something went wrong during the request and finally use `complete:` when the request is finished (regardless of whether it was successful or not).

With this knowledge, you can better write your code to *catch* the data returned from the server at *the right time*.

```
var email_number = '';

// check if page refreshed or reloaded
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    var hash    = window.location.hash;
    var mailfolder = hash.split('/')[0].replace('#', '');
    var emailid = 'SUJmaWg4RTFRQkViS1RlUzV3K1NPdz09';
    get_emailno(emailid, mailfolder);
}

function get_emailno(emailid, mailfolder) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getemailnumber.php',
        type: 'POST',

        data : {
            emailid: emailid,
            mailfolder: mailfolder
        },

        success: function(data)
        {
            // sufficient to get returned data
            email_number = data;

            // use email_number here
            alert(email_number); // alert it
            console.log(email_number); // or log it
            $('body').html(email_number); // or append to DOM
        }
    });
}
```